# Basic vite + react template does not work on firefox but does work on chromium

Tags: reactjs, firefox

I just got a really weird bug: the default template that I get when initializing my repository with vite + react fails to work on firefox while it works normally in chromium. I have no error, but clicking on the button that contains a counter does not increase the counter that is defined as:

```
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  return (
    <> […]
        <button onClick={() => setCount((count) => count + 1)}>
          count is {count}
        </button>
    <>)
}
```

Thanks to the react devtool, I can see that after clicking the button, the components are re-rendered, but the state does not seem to be updated (doing a profiling shows that only the hook is updated, but not the state)… But on the other hand, if I put a `onClick={() => setCount((count) => {console.log(count); return count+1;})}` I can see in the console that the printed number increases:

[image]

Some other screenshots:

[image]

And some profiling while clicking the button:

[image]

Note that I have javascript enabled, and I also tried to disable adblock with no success.

Firefox version 109.0.1

Comment: Does it work at all with firefox? In my case it does not. I can open the link http://localhost:5174/ui/ perfectly with chrome, but firefox acts if there is no server running at this port. Any tips?

Comment: @EinEsellesEniE For me it works in FF yes. Why do you add the `/ui` part? At least on the basic vite template I don't need it. Maybe ask another question if it does not solve your issue.

Comment: the ui part is only for a specific application. I tested with the template and without ui. I asked a seperate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77353557/can-firefox-be-used-as-a-development-browser-for-react-with-vite/77354270#77354270

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I just restarted firefox and the problem seems to be gone… no idea what was wrong, I hope it won't happen again!