# Can Firefox be used as a development browser for react with vite?

Tags: reactjs, firefox, vite

I started a new react project with

```
npm create vite@latest my-app -- --template react-ts
```

and did

```
  cd my-vue-app
  npm install
  npm run dev
```

Now it says that I can open the website `http://localhost:5174/`.

I can open it in Chrome. But I can't open it in Firefox. Firefox acts if there isn't a server running at this port at all. It has no connection to localhost:5174.

Is Firefox in general able to open this website and I have a local problem? Or does the vite development server does not work with firefox in general. I haven't found a browser compatibility list on the vite website. And this guy here [Basic vite + react template does not work on firefox but does work on chromium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76966858/basic-vite-react-template-does-not-work-on-firefox-but-does-work-on-chromium) said in his answer that he was able to open the website in firefox.

Answer (score 1):

There are no restrictions for opening apps on the localhost, you can use any browser or program like Postman. There is probably a problem with your Firefox. Also try to open the app at http://127.0.0.1:5174/ and check if it works without an alias.

Comment: Good idea. Bit using 127.0.0.1 did not work in my case. The first get request the browser sends is not working. It says NS_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

Comment: Has it ever been resolved? Still getting this in FireFox.